# PivotTable divide Price sum equally by field

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have the following table

```
Cost Center|Price
680        |10
680        |11
680        |10
900        |10
600        |10
```

The price sum is 51, however I need to get the sum and divide it by the distinct cost centers (3) resulting equally in 17 for each cost-center.
And in my pivot table I'd like it to show the cost-center and that it'll pay 17.

Basically I want to divide the total price equally and show what each cost center will be paying.
I've tried using COUNT and SUM in calculated fields however it never ends in the correct value.

Answer (score 0):

How about using [GETPIVOTDATA function](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/getpivotdata-function-8c083b99-a922-4ca0-af5e-3af55960761f?ui=en-us&rs=en-us&ad=us) to get the value that you need?

Step 1

Create a table from data source first, when you are inserting a PivotTable, please check the box of “Add this data to the Data Mode”, which is at the bottom of “Create PivotTable”.

[image]

Step 2

Drag “Cost Center” into Rows, then drag “Cost Center” and “Price” into Values. Please make sure one is the “Distinct Count of Cost Center”, another one is the “Sum of Price” in Values, if not, you may choose the correct calculation in Value Field Settings.

[image]

Step 3

Select a cell above an existed PivotTable, enter “=”, then click the cell of Grand Total of Sum of Price (51), enter “/”, click the cell of Grand Total of Distinct Count of Cost Center (3), press Enter, you would get 17.

[image]

If there is new data added in table, please click Refresh All, the pivot table and the value of GETPIVOTDATA function would be updated.